# Show multiple images from media folder directly to django template

Tags: html, django

I have a set of images in media folder(200-300).I need to show these images to front end of the django(html)
Media images are random images and there is no model too. Is it possible to show images of media directly to django templates?

Comment: You could do `os.listdir(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` for a list of all the files. Then put the list on the context.

Comment: i passed the list in a context to template. It is showing the lists..but images are not loading @RobertAguilar

Comment: Hey its worked!!! Thanks @RobertAguilar

Comment: @RobertAguilar  while iam loading images it is very slow ,i need to load atleast 15 images per page. is there any alternative solutions to reduce the lag while loading?

Comment: You'd probably have to paginate them somehow. Since the images are not tied to a model, I'm not sure how you would go about that.